# Startup.cs equivalent in Python for Azure Functions / Dependency Injection Python

Tags: python, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am a C# developer who has been tasked with converting some deployed C# Azure functions (mostly webhooks / SB) to Python.

I am struggling with the concept of the python equivalency to dependency injection.

Take for example an api client class that makes calls continuously to some 3rd party API to push and pull data. In .NET if i had a webhook function that needed to use this api client, i would initiate a singleton service in the startup.cs class, and inject it into my azure webhook function. This is advantageous cause i can handle the token refreshing and what not inside of the service class itself and have the token stored in memory, instead of having to re-create an instance of the api client class each time the webhook is fired.

How do i do this in Python? Or what is the right method of doing something similar in a similar environment (Azure functions) where we store tokens in memory AND create a service once and use the same service across multiple functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- While not being using widely because the way python is setup, dependency injection can be implemented using python. There is a python package called [dependency-injector](https://pypi.org/project/dependency-injector/#:%7E:text=Dependency%20Injector%20is%20a%20dependency%20injection%20microframework%20for,Injector%20framework%20are:%20Easy,%20smart,%20and%20pythonic%20style.) which helps in implementing di.
- We should not store the tokens in local memory of the function as functions are stateless and serverless what that means is we don't have either control or knowledge about the servers on which our function is running thus we don't know how long they will be stored in the memory instead of this once you acquire the tokens add them to the `azure keyvault`, so that you can use them frequently.
- you can share a python class among the functions just place them a separate folder and import them in your functions.

```py
from ..common_files import test_file
```

Refer this [article](https://www.netguru.com/blog/dependency-injection-with-python-make-it-easy) by Szymon miks for examples of dependency Injection in python

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level#import-behavior) on the sharing file between functions.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-python?tabs=azure-cli) on azure keyvault about retrieving keys