# How to wire dependency injection for azure function python v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am a .net developer recently started using python, I am trying to create a Azure function v2 using python and looking for help on how to inject dependencies into my function. I looked at various examples of python dependency injection and able to do that in general. But I couldn't to figure it out where to call my bootstraping.

In .net this can done simply by extending FunctionStarup class, I cannot find such thing in python azure-functions package. Microsoft documentation also doesn't mentioned anything about Dependency Injection in python function v2 programming guide [python developer guidance for azure function v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators)

> This is partial code snippet of sample I tried but it didn't work. I used kink for DI in below example

> Class I am trying to Inject

```
       class IocService:
        def __init__(self, message: str):
            self.message = message
    
        def say_hello(self, name: str) -> str:
            return f"{self.message}, {name}!"
```

> #Function definition using blueprint

```
from kink import inject
import logging

from IocService import IocService

import azure.functions as func 

bp = func.Blueprint() 
@inject
@bp.route(route="default_template") 
def default_template(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context, service: IocService) -> func.HttpResponse: 
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 
    #ioc_service = context.get_service(IocService)

    name = req.params.get('name') 
    if not name: 
        try: 
            req_body = req.get_json() 
        except ValueError: 
            pass 
        else: 
            name = req_body.get('name') 

    if name: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP-triggered function " 
            f"executed successfully.") 
    else: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            "This HTTP-triggered function executed successfully. " 
            "Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a" 
            " personalized response.", 
            status_code=200 
        )
```

> function_app.py

```
import azure.functions as func 
from http_blueprint import bp
from bootstrap import start_up

print("before start up")
start_up()
print("After start up")
app = func.FunctionApp() 
app.register_functions(bp)
```

> Here below is the error message

```
>       File "<path>\function_app.py", line 2, in <module>
>     from http_blueprint import bp   File "<path>\http_blueprint.py", line 9, in <module>
>     @inject
>      ^^^^^^   File "<path>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kink\inject.py",
> line 203, in inject
>     return _decorator(_service)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "<Path>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kink\inject.py",
> line 193, in _decorator
>     service_function = _decorate(bind or {}, _service, container)
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "<Path>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kink\inject.py",
> line 105, in _decorate
>     service in [ABC.__init__, _no_init] or service.__name__ == "_no_init"
> 
>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators

When i run the function by removing injection from httptrigger method, the logs are showing very interesting things:

1. It printed the logs in the function
2. Then printed the logs in function_app.py

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the dependent class or method in a different file in the Function Trigger directory and call it inside your Function App. Refer below:-

My **`sidblueprint.py`**:-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from IocService import IocService



app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


bp = func.Blueprint() 

@bp.route(route="HttpRequest") 
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    message = "Hello from IocService"  # Define your message
    ioc_service = IocService(message)  # Instantiate the IocService

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        response = ioc_service.say_hello(name)
        return func.HttpResponse(response, status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "name with query string or body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

My **`function_app.py`**:-

```py
import azure.functions as func 
from sidblueprint import bp

app = func.FunctionApp() 

app.register_functions(bp)
```

My **`IocService.py`:-**

```py
class IocService:
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message

    def say_hello(self, name: str) -> str:
        return f"{self.message}, {name}!"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

According to this ***[SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313772/startup-cs-equivalent-in-python-for-azure-functions-dependency-injection-pytho)*** you can make use of **`dependency_injector`** module in python to inject Dependency injection within Python scripts and Functions.

**My `sidblueprint.py` with dependency_injector module**:-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
# from IocService import IocService

from dependency_injector import containers, providers

from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject

class IocService:
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message

    def say_hello(self, name: str) -> str:
        return f"{self.message}, {name}!"

class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    ioc_service = providers.Factory(
        IocService,
        message="Hello"  # Set your default message here
    )

container = Container()


app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


bp = func.Blueprint() 
@inject
@bp.route(route="HttpRequest") 
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    message = "Hello from IocService"  # Define your message
    ioc_service = IocService(message)  # Instantiate the IocService

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        response = ioc_service.say_hello(name)
        return func.HttpResponse(response, status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "name with query string or body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**requirements.txt:-**

```
azure-functions
dependency_injector
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. I might overlooked your code example or due lack of my understanding, I didn't understand or see where did you injected the IocService, you actually instantiated the IocService class inside function method. I am looking for how to inject as function parameters or a from constructor.

Comment: Tried with some changes with your code and example from dependency-injector docs
`@inject
@bp.route(route="HttpRequest") 
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, iocService: IocService = Provide[Container.ioc_service]) -> func.HttpResponse:`
 but getting error called 
`cannot load the function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'iocService'}` but i couldn't find any function.json file, is there anything else i am missing.

Comment: function.json is required in Python Function v1 and not V2, In order to understand how Azure Python Function v2 folder works refer here- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model/ba-p/3665168 and here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#folder-structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dependency_injector` to inject dependencies. Refer below:

> Related Package:
>
> - Azure Functions - Python V2
> - Dependency Injector: [Introduction Doc](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/introduction/index.html)

**Project Layout**

```
./
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── services.py
│   ├── containers.py
│   └── hp_blueprint.py
├── venv/
├── function_app.py
└── requirements.txt
```

**My `hp_blueprint.py`:**

> In these function binding triggers, we can't use parameter injection to get dependency service. And we will get parameter error that dependency service parameters need to be declared in `function.json` if we use this way in the functions with function trigger binding `@bp.route('myroute')`.

To adapt function app python V2, we can define a function to get container instance. And use it to get providers.
And We can use `{service name}()` to get service instance.

See more details:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject

from app.containers import Container
from app.services import IocService

http_bp = func.Blueprint() 

@inject
def get_container(global_container : Container = Provide[Container.global_container])
    return global_container

@http_bp.route(route="test")
@http_bp.http_type("GET")
def testtrigger(
    req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 

    global_container : Container = get_container()
    service: IocService = global_container.iocservice()

    return func.HttpResponse( 
        body=service.test(),
        status_code= 200)
```

**My `services.py` and `container.py`**:

Reference Document:

- We use **Self Provider** to save container instance. So that, we can use `Provide` parameter binding to get container instance. See more details in [Inject Container Instance By Self Provider](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/inject_self.html)
- We use **container** to save our dependency injection structure, including Factory, Singleton, Configuration and so on. please refer to [multiple container](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/examples/application-multiple-containers.html) if you want to split container in several modules or domains.

```
class IocService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "Test"

    def test(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.message}"
```

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers

from .services import IocService


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    global_container = Provider.Self()

    iocservice = providers.Factory(IocService)
```

**Container Wiring Code**

We need to find the usage scope of this container. And add wiring codes in `function_app.py`. And you can get more details about `wire` method from [Wiring Document](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/wiring.html#wiring-with-modules-and-packages) and [Wire API](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/api/containers.html#dependency_injector.containers.DynamicContainer.traverse)

[image]

Example below:

```
from .containers import Container

# init dependencies for Resource type.
container = Container()
container.init_resources()
container.wire(packages=["your package name"])
```

There are two method to wire usage scope, including **modules** and **packages**. I wire container with a package. Container walks recursively over the package modules. That means that `Container` can be used in `app.*`